# How to do an inequality join in Apache Drill?

Tags: sql, apache-drill

I am trying to run a query in Drill that requires inequality joins (such as ‘on a.event_time >= b.event_time and a.event_time < b.next_event_time’). I am getting the error that Drill does not support inequality joins, and that is also what I am reading online.

Are there any work arounds to use in drill to get the same results without using an inequality join? All I can think of is expanding one of my tables to include duplicate rows for every iteration of the field I am trying to join on, but I am guessing there is a more straightforward way Drill users get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Table1
 JOIN Table2
   ON Table1.time > Table2.time
```

Can you try ?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Table1, Table2
 WHERE Table1.time > Table2.time
```

Comment: I cannot; I am not using the inequalities to filter or limit my data. On the contrary, i need to join rows where values in the field found in the second table that are between or equal to values in the first table.

Comment: My  two query are equivalent. That is why I ask If you are trying to do first query, second query will return the same result

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky but I was able to get it to work by duplicating and bundling the logic of the join in the "WHERE" clause, then adding an OR to the opposite of the join.

So for example if you want to do

```
SELECT * FROM
    ORDERS as Ord
LEFT JOIN Customers as Cus
    ON Cus.CustomerID = Ord.CustomerID
    AND Cus.CustomerType <> 'Employee'
```

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    ORDERS as Ord
LEFT JOIN Customers as Cus
    ON Cus.CustomerID = Ord.CustomerID
WHERE ((Cus.CustomerID = Ord.CustomerID
    AND Cus.CustomerType <> 'Employee') OR (Cus.CustomerID <> Ord.CustomerID))
```